# how to generate a statement from the file base on the current date?

Tags: java

Scenario: I am going to make tip of the day as assignment, I tried a lot and can do up-to below level :
my question is how to generate a statement from the file base on the current date, if a statement is already showed for current date, don't again show that, get another random statement from file.
P.S: sorry for my bad english

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
class FileRead {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<String> tip = new ArrayList<String>();
        Random r= new Random();
        int n= r.nextInt(10);
        try{


            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("d:/MyPhrases.txt");
            // use DataInputStream to read binary NOT text
            // DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            String strLine;
            //Read File Line By Line
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // write the content on the arraylist
                tip.add(br.readLine());
            }
            //Close the input stream
            in.close();
            // Print the content on the console
            while (tip != null) {
                //Collections.shuffle(tip);
                System.out.println (tip.get(n).toString());
                System.exit(0);
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should give a snippet of what your file looks like.

Comment: Your question is very unclear as to what you want to achieve. A few lines of your file would help. We don't know how you determine the date. Is the date in a line of the file?

Comment: Also I don't get the random part of your program. What is supposed to be random?

Comment: in my file I have proverbs that each time should be display

Comment: I want that my program check the date of today and generate a proverb, if date is changed, then show another proverb, totally everday I want to show a proverb but not duplicate, I want shuffle

Comment: Ok I don't get the date part. Do you mean you only want to be able to run the program one time per day?

Comment: no, if for current date, the program show a proverb befor, then for all of this day show that proverb. and if date is changed then show another proverb

Comment: Do you want to check the exact date like 11/23/2013 or just the day like Monday, Tuesday?

Answer (score 0):

For this line,

```
tip.add(br.readLine());
```

I believe you want

```
tip.add(strline);
```

If you used the first one, the list would add the next line, instead of the current line.

**Edit:**

```
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null && i <= n) {
     if (!tip.contains(strLine)) {
         tip.add(strLine);
         break;
     }
     n++;
}
```